# How to set-up Contacts to work with Google Contacts?

Tags: 15.04, contacts, online-accounts

First, I added my Google Account to the app **Online Accounts** found in the Unity Launcher of Ubuntu 15.04:

[image]

Second, I launched the app **Contacts** from the Unity launcher and clicked on the button `Online Accounts`:

[image]

However, clicking the button does not produce any subsequent action.

What are the steps required to set-up **Contacts** to work with an online Google Account?

Comment: please refer [here](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8226-how-to-sync-evolution-with-googles-pim-apps)

Comment: You need to use evolution. If you couldn't set up contacts through Gnome-Contacts, then file a bug. A better option is to use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-google-contacts-with-evolution-addressbooks).

Comment: Thanks to both of you! So, Evolution and the above Contacts app are not the same apps? Why does Contacts provide the button "Online Accounts" if it is not functional?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. They are different apps. Both uses same backend `evolution-data-server`. And these are Gnome apps works better with Gnome-Online-Accounts and not with Ubuntu-online-Accounts.